# Why some module can not load maven independencies when open a project use IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

My project has some modules,when I open the project ,some modules can load maven independencies automatically,but some not.I have change the module sdk,java compiler target type code to 1.8,but still can not load the maven project.How to fix it?My os is windows10 and idea is 2020.3.2.I have install openjdk1.8 in my system.
[image: The module that can not load maven dependencies]

[image: The module that can load maven dependencies]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to change maven version from bundled to downloaded and enable auto-import

Comment: The idea bundled maven version is apache-maven-3.6.3,I also install 3.6.3 in my computer.Both can not work.I attend to  use the lower maven version and try.

Comment: Does the project build on plain command line without any issue? Because there seemed to be dependencies missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set *JDK for importer* to java 8 and after click to *Reload All Maven Projects* button.

[image: JDK for Importer]
[image]

Comment: Try 'mvn clean install -DskipTests -U' command from maven tool.